chrome captureVisibleTab behavior
OS - macOS Sonoma
I am trying to capture images of all the tabs of a Chrome Window B which is launched by another Chrome Window A. This process is part of an extension. Following are the possibilities
B can be in

foreground
background of A
background of any other Application window like Slack, for example

Workflow is

extension loads code where Window A, with relevant permission activeTab, opens Window B.
Window B opens 4 tabs, where first tab contains Take Screenshot button.
User takes action on a Button on first Tab of Window B to initiate screenshot capture.
Algorithm triggers that iteratively makes every tab is active and injects a script is in active Tab's foreground, which sends the message to the background to take screenshot.

Following is the code
manifest.json
{
"manifest_version": 3,
"name": "Screenshot Extension",
"version": "1.0",
"permissions": [
  "tabs",  "scripting", "activeTab"],
"host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "*://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
"background": {
  "service_worker": "background.js"
},
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }
],
"action": {
  "default_popup": "popup.html",
  "default_icon": {
    "16": "images/icon.png",
    "48": "images/icon.png",
    "128": "images/icon.png"
  }
}
  }

content.js
console.log('in content script'); 
  
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "captureTab" }, (response) => {
  
  console.log('logging status: ' + response.status);
  if (response.dataUrl) {
    // Optionally handle the captured image data URL here
    console.log('Captured image URL:', response.dataUrl);
  }
});

background.js
let captureVisibleTab;
let cwid;
let windowBId;

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
      id: "createWindowB",
      title: "Create Window B",
      contexts: ["action"]
    });
  });

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  console.log('launching window');
  createWindowB();
  });
  
  function createWindowB() {
    const urls = [
      chrome.runtime.getURL("permission.html"),
      "https://stackoverflow.com/",
      "https://google.com/",
      "https://cricbuzz.com/"
    ];
  
    chrome.windows.create({
      url: urls,
      type: "normal",
      focused: true
    }, (window) => {
      windowBId = window.id;
      console.log('Window B created with ID:', window.id);
    });
  }


// Listener for messages to start the screenshot process
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (request.action === 'startScreenshots') {
      console.log('received start taking screen shots');
      startTakingScreenshots();
    }
  });

  function startTakingScreenshots() {
    chrome.tabs.query({ windowId: windowBId}, (tabs) => {
      tabs.forEach((tab, index) => {
        if (index > 0) { // Skip the first tab (index 0)
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('starting to take screenshot');
            chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { active: true }, () => {
              chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: { tabId: tab.id },
                files: ['content.js']
              });
            });
          }, index * 6000); // Delay to allow the tab to activate and render
        }
      });
    });
  }
  
captureVisibleTab = (callback) => {
  chrome.windows.getCurrent((currentWindow) => {
      cwid = currentWindow.id;
      console.log(`Current window ID: ${cwid} & window B id: ${windowBId}`);
    });

  if (cwid !== windowBId) return;

  console.log('invoking captured tab with current window id: ' + cwid);
  chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(windowBId, { format: 'png' }, (dataUrl) => {
    console.log('Captured tab image data URL:', dataUrl);
    // Pass the dataUrl to the callback
    if (callback) callback(dataUrl);
  });
};

// Listener to handle messages from the content script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
if (request.action === "captureTab" && captureVisibleTab) {
  captureVisibleTab((dataUrl) => {
    console.log(dataUrl);
    sendResponse({ status: "Captured", dataUrl: dataUrl });
  });
  // Return true to indicate that we will respond asynchronously
  return true;
}
});

windowB.js
document.getElementById('startScreenshots').addEventListener('click', () => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'startScreenshots' });
  });

permission.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Window B</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      margin: 20px;
    }
    button {
      padding: 10px 20px;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Take Screenshots</h1>
  <button id="startScreenshots">Start Taking Screenshots</button>
  <script src="windowB.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

popup.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Mouse Cursor Mover</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Click to Move Mouse Cursor</h1>
</body>
</html>

Observations: on loading extension, Window B is launched. I click on the button in the first tab to take snapshot, i observe the following behaviour

Window B is foreground - Success (Screenshots of Tabs are captured)
Window B is in background of another Application - Success
Window B is in background of Window A, and completely overshadowed by it - Failure
Window B is in background of Window A, and visible even by smallest of margin behind Window A - Success
Window B is minimized - Failure

I can think of the reason for working on scenarios 1 and probably for 5, however, I cannot work out reason why 2 & 4 work while 3 fails.
Will appreciate suggestions or probably pointing out if I overlooked any point here.
